# Passing String parameter Value Through angular Service parameter Value is Automatically Appends Some Special Character

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's my **Angular controller**

```
//Save And Update
$scope.AddUpdateBusinessType = function() {

    var businessType = {
        Code: $scope.businessCode,
        BusiType: $scope.businessType
    };

    var getBusinessTypeAction = $scope.BusinessTypeAction;

    if (getBusinessTypeAction == "Update") {
        businessType.BusinessTypeId = $scope.businessTypeId;
        var getBusinessTypeData = businessTypeService.updateBusinessType(businessType);
        getBusinessTypeData.then(function (msg) {
            GetAllBusinessType();
            $scope.ClearBusinessTypeForm();
            alert("Record Updated Successful");
            $scope.BusinessTypeAction = "";
            $scope.divBusinessType = false;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in Updating Record');
        });
    } else {

**// Save Section**
            var getExistBusinessCode = businessTypeService.checkBusinessTypeCode(businessType.Code);
            getExistBusinessCode.then(function (businessTypeCode) {
                debugger;
                if (businessTypeCode == true) {
                    alert('Business Type Code Already Exist');
                } else {
                    debugger;
                    var getBusinessTypeData = businessTypeService.addBusinessType(businessType);
                    getBusinessTypeData.then(function (msg) {
                        GetAllBusinessType();
                        $scope.ClearBusinessTypeForm();
                        alert("Record Added Successful");
                        $scope.divBusinessType = false;
                    }, function () {
                        alert("Error Occured In Saving Data");
                    });
                }
            },function() {
                alert('Error Occured While Checking Records');
            });


        }
    }
```

In the above code Save Section I am trying to check if a value is exists in a database so I'm passing a string value to: **checkBusinessTypeCode(businessType.Code)** Service.When I Debug and See Value its Seems Normal.

Here's My Service:

```
//Check Business Code
this.checkBusinessTypeCode = function (businessTypeCode) {
    debugger;
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/BusinessType/CheckBusinessTypeDetailByCode",
        params: {
            businessTypeCode: JSON.stringify(businessTypeCode)
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

But when Passing To Controller string value I get some unexpected behavior.
two `\\` always appear automatically

example 
**"\"stringvalue\""**

Comment: does the `businessTypecode` come into the service wrapped in quotes? If so, then `JSON.stringify` will escape those quotes before adding its own, which would explain why this happens.
`JSON.stringify("hello")` in a browser console gives `""hello""`, which when you receive it over the wire, will look like `"\"hello\""`. That shouldn't be a problem as long as the receiving service is expecting to receive a string that reads literally `"hello"` as opposed to just `hello`

Comment: Is the issue resolved from your perspective, or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Still Having Above Problem
but as a quick solution i did code as follows

```
public bool _CheckBusinessTypeDetailByCode(string businessTypeCode)
    {
        string bisCode = businessTypeCode.Replace("\"", "");
        bool isExist;
        isExist = _IBusinessTypeRepository.IsExist(x => x.IsActive && !x.IsDelete && x.Code == bisCode);
        return isExist;
    }
```

I don't know is it bad practice or not , any way it is solved my problem.
Before did this modification 
 string businessTypeCode always gives value as

**"\"somevalue\""**